# How to instrument function with record arguments?

Tags: clojure

I have a protocol `Foo`.
I also have a function `make-test-foo` which constructs test version (mock) of `Foo`, record `Bar`.

How do I instrument (`clojure.spec.test.alpha/instrument`) a function `fizz` which accepts
(as one of its arguments) `Foo`, so that `make-test-foo` is used?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you might need to spec a `Foo`, and then use `make-test-foo` in the generator for the `Foo` spec. This assumes you're okay with the test `Foo` instance being generated for all cases where a `Foo` is needed in spec.

You might also look at the [Check and instrument](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_combining_check_and_instrument) section of the Spec Guide.